# How to arrange multiple rows?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I’m currently learning about HTML and CSS grids. So far I have created two blocks with different color and items with content within. However I haven’t figure out how to organize the elements in two rows. I’m planning to add interactive animations for every grid item. So it would be useful to make a better use of the screen space.

Here is the code I’m currently using:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>  

        <style>
            .flex-container {
              display: flex;
              background-color: darkslategrey;
              padding: 10px;
              grid-auto-columns: auto;
              grid-auto-rows: auto;
              
            }

            div  {
                display: block;
                width: 300px;
                border: 15px ;
                padding: 50px;
                margin: 20px;
                background-color: sandybrown;
                }
            
            .flex-container > div {
              background-color: #f1f1f1;
              margin: 10px;
              padding: 20px;
              font-size: 30px;
              grid-template-columns: 200px;
            }

            

            .grid-item  {
                
                border: 4px solid black;
                width: 120px;
                height: 50px;
                padding: 20px;
                font-size: 30px;
                text-align: center;

                
                        }
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            
            <h1>&nbsp;&nbsp; Game</h1>

            <div class="table">
                <h2>Test element</h2>
            </div>
            
            <section class="flex-container">
              <div class="grid-item">1</div>
              <div class="grid-item">2</div>
              <div class="grid-item">3</div>
              <div class="grid-item">4</div>
              <div class="grid-item">5</div>
              <div class="grid-item">6</div>
              <div class="grid-item">7</div>
              <div class="grid-item">8</div>
              <div class="grid-item">9</div>
               
            </section>
            
           </body>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest separate flexboxes within the large one to organize into rows. The biggest one (A here) will use `flex-display: column;` to make the rows. The 2nd biggest (B here) will use `flex-display: row;` to organize the grid-items in each row. Add your `grid-item`s to the B flexbox and organize their order in the html with `div`s like you already are.

```
.flexboxA{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flexboxB{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.grid-item{
  border: 4px solid black;
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it to be in two rows exactly?

Otherwise you can use property: `flex-wrap: wrap`.
This makes the items go to the next line when there is no more space in the current line.

Comment: Thanks. Although the other answer was useful as well, that property worked fine for this purpose

Comment: @MauricioVázquez Happy it helped. Either mark this answer or the other one as accepted.